# Is there a typescript version of AsyncMethod().Result?

Tags: typescript

In C# I can call the result of an asynchronous method synchronously by calling the `Result` property.

For instance:

```
var returnVal = AsyncMethod().Result;
```

What is the equivalent of this in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `async`/`await` that is analogous to that, but nothing precisely the same. Or at least there is no such thing when running in browsers or Node. The `Result` property is on the `Task<T>` class. The equivalent of that in TypeScript is `Promise<T>`, which is the type that describes promise objects.

TypeScript is just JS at runtime. JS runtimes are aggressively asynchronous, because JS is designed to work without multiple threads. Instead there is a single thread that has to be yielded to ensure cooperation between tasks. So JS strongly favours non-blocking APIs.

The hidden side-effect of `Result` is that it if no result is available yet, it blocks the thread until the result arrives. In the JS world, this would block the *only* thread, so none of your other code would be able to execute, and that would most likely stop the result arriving (unless the promise was returned directly by some system call).

Using `Result` is a hacky and risky trick even in the CLR. It frequently leads to deadlocks. It's better in the CLR to use `async` everywhere if you're going to use it anywhere. Let the asynchronous nature "ripple up" to the highest level (e.g. controller method or `Main`).

And in JS (and hence TS) you have no choice but to do the right thing and be consistently async. It's not too difficult. If you have a function:

```
function f() {

    const x = downloadSomething(); // x is a promise, I want the result
}
```

Instead write:

```
async function f() {

    const x = await downloadSomething();
}
```

Now `f()` also returns a promise, and so the asynchronicity "ripples up". But this is exactly the same as you should be doing in C#, where possible.

Comment: Is there some point at the top where initial execution is started synchronously like a console apps static Main() method?

Comment: Not really. There is the “top level” at which scripts run, but they shouldn’t block for too long in there either.